# Is there a FIFO per-process FIFO guarantee on MPI_Isend?

Tags: mpi, fifo

I'm doing a bunch of MPI_Isend calls to a number of processes to distribute some data. On each call, I'm storing the resulting MPI_Request in an array. After all the MPI_Isend calls are made, I do a MPI_Waitall on the requests.

The order of the messages is important, i.e. I want each process to receive the messages in
the same order that I've sent them. This is because for each piece of data I'm sending, I'm also distributing some meta-data with it, using a separate MPI_Isend call. I think this is a bad idea, but I don't know of an alternative. Clearly, the meta-data must arrive prior to the data, so I need the FIFO guarantee. Is this the case for what I'm doing?

I don't care about different processes receiving data in different order, I'm only interested in individual processes getting the data in the right order. Is this documented anywhere? I'm using the MPICH2 implementation.

I want to distribute an array of doubles with some data associated to it, but the "tag" is too limited.

Answer (score 1):

In MPI, you are guaranteed that all messages on the same communicator/tag/rank combo will be received in the same order they were sent.

For example, in this example:

```
if (rank == 0)
  MPI_Send(buf, 10, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
else if (rank == 1)
  MPI_Recv(buf, 10, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

all of the messages received by rank 1 would be in the same order as they were sent from rank 0. This is also true for the non-blocking versions (`MPI_ISEND` / `MPI_IRECV`).

This is not true if you use different tags. For example:

```
if (rank == 0) {
  MPI_Send(buf, 10, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Send(buf, 10, MPI_INT, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
} else if (rank == 1) {
  MPI_Recv(buf, 10, MPI_INT, 1, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  MPI_Recv(buf, 10, MPI_INT, 1, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
}
```

would not necessarily receive the message in the same order that they were sent because they use different tags.

For more information, you can look at Section 3.5 of the [MPI-3.0 Standard](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.0/mpi30-report.pdf) (page 40).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, if several messages can be matched by a `recv` call, MPI guarentees the order of messages for each sender (but the order across different senders are not), whatever the tag is, whichever the send mode is (the send mode only affects the sender's code).
The common case is that one process (sender) keep sending data to another process (receiver), so the order here is FIFO.

Apparently this is guarenteed per communicator (because it envolves the *match* of `recv`). There doesn't seem to be any guarentees among different communicators.

Therefore, the answer by Wesley Bland is not correct. In his examples, the order is always guarenteed FIFO.